# Configurar symfony 4 - Monolog

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Buen dia

Estoy migrando un proyecto de symfony 3.4 a 4.4

Realice la configuración y cambios de las depredaciones para symfony flex y la configuración que encontre que es necesaria para symfony 4.4

El problema radica en la cantidad de memoria usada para realizar las consultas y procesos. Esto se soluciona aumentando la memoria en mi servidor de php, pero no quisiera hacer esto

Hay alguna manera de configurar monolog o symfony para solucionar este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está seguro es Monolog el que provoca el desbordamiento de memoria?? Publique la configuración de log que tiene.

Comment: Creo que tiene que ver con la cantidad de logs que se registran